# How to save binary null in char

Tags: c, binary

Sample original binary image file :

```
Ã¿ÃÃ¿Ã ^@^PJFIF^@^A^A^@^@^A^@^A^@^@Ã¿Ã^@<84>^@
```

Note :

```
^@ = null
```

Result binary image file :

```
Ã¿ÃÃ¿Ã ^PJFIF^A^A^A^AÃ¿Ã<84>
```

^@ missing

Sample code :

```
char sendBuffer[17500];
char buffer[16000];
char sendBuffer2[17500];
char temp[10];

inputFile = fopen("image.jpg", "rb");
fseek(inputFile , 0, SEEK_SET);
fread(buffer, fileSize, 1, inputFile );

for (j = 0; j < fileSize; ++j)
{
    sprintf(sendBuffer, "%c", ((char *)buffer)[j]);

    if (((char *)buffer)[j] == '\x00')
    {
        sprintf(temp, "%c", buffer[j]);
        strcat(sendBuffer2, temp);
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(sendBuffer2, sendBuffer);
    }
```

Can binary null value store in char ? 
I already tried with the above code, but binary null gone. How to save binary null in char ? or is there a other type data to save it?
i want to send binary file like jpg with udp socket.

Comment: The nulls are still there. They just can't be printed out, since nulls can't be displayed.

Comment: ís `inputFile` same as `file`?

Comment: what is it you are trying to achieve? you seem to be just copying bytes to the `sendBuffer2`, why not use `buffer` directly?

Comment: you are also better off not printing characters from a binary file since as you suspected, there are non-printable characters in such a file. if you want to print the contents why not instead write the hex values of each byte.

Comment: @claptrap my achieve is i want to send binary file like jpg with udp socket. per segment about 16KB. i must read content binary file per 16kb. the problem i can't save binary null in char.

Comment: if you write on a socket, just write part of the buffer and an offset. e.g. `fwrite(buffer + offset, size, 1, fp)` then increase `offset += size;` and continue calling `fwrite `(or `write`) until you have sent all.

Answer (score 3):

The printf() family of functions and also strcat() assume that the null char means "end of string." What you have is not a null-terminated string though. So don't use any of the printf() functions nor strcat(). Copy your data with something like memcpy() and specify the exact length of the data you want to copy. If you need to copy byte by byte, then simply do a direct assignment and keep two indices around, one that gives the current tail of your output buffer and one for the head of your input buffer.

Your code is confusing though and it's not clear what you expect it to do. Here's some example code that tries to implement your original intent but without assuming that null-chars are terminating the data sequence:

```
char sendBuffer[17500];
char buffer[16000];
char sendBuffer2[17500];
size_t sendbuf2_len = 0;
char temp[10];

inputFile = fopen("image.jpg", "rb");
fseek(inputFile , 0, SEEK_SET);
fread(buffer, fileSize, 1, inputFile );

for (j = 0; j < fileSize; ++j) {
    sendBuffer[0] = buffer[j];        
    if (buffer[j] == '\x00') {
        temp[0] = buffer[j];
        // Append.
        sendBuffer2[sendbuf2_len++] = temp[0];
    } else {
        // Append.
        sendBuffer2[sendbuf2_len++] = sendBuffer[0];
    }
```

But it doesn't make sense. Your if branch just copies the same data anyway, since temp[0] and sendBuffer[0] will contain the same byte.

In your original code, you have:

```
sprintf(sendBuffer, "%c", ((char *)buffer)[j]);
```

And then in the first `if` branch you have:

```
sprintf(temp, "%c", buffer[j]);
strcat(sendBuffer2, temp);
```

In both cases, your byte is `buffer[j]`. So your `if` statement doesn't really do anything useful. The same byte is appended to `sendBuffer2` in both cases. (And of course note that strcat() won't work anyway, since it assumes null-terminated strings, it won't just append one single character.)

Comment: thanks, but i'm still don't understand. can u give me a sample code ? i'm really appreciate it. thanks.

Comment: Your code is confusing though (what do you expect `sendBuffer` and `sendBuffer2` to contain? Just one char? Are you trying to append to them? Do you want to empty them at some point?) I added some example code nonetheless.

Comment: thanks for the code. i tried your code,but the result just Ã¿ÃÃ¿Ã.
sendBuffer = just to get 1 character from buffer. this buffer i will strcat if that character not binary null.
sendBuffer2 = buffer for save all binary file character. and i will send this sendBuffer2 with udp socket.
i think for binary you must compare and strcat 1 by 1 to a char.

Comment: @Mari_Yaguchi If `sendBuffer` and `temp` are only supposed to hold one byte, then your code makes no sense, since `temp[0]` and `sendBuffer[0]` will contain the same byte in both branches. I provided some code regardless. You should fix the logic of your code.

Answer (score 2):

string in C is a convention, that it is zero-terminated. So what you need is a binary string of fixed/known length. And you need to use other functions than strlen and sprintf, which take length into account.